# CodeIgniter PDO - Call to undefined method CI_DB_pdo_mysql_driver::num_rows()

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, pdo

I'm trying to code a web login/registration system and I'm getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_pdo_mysql_driver::num_rows() in (path to model) on line 7`

I tried also using rowCount() instead and it still didn't work.

That's the model:

```
<?php

class Member_model extends CI_Model {
    public function can_log_in() {
        $query = $this->db->select('password')->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            if (password_verify($this->input->post('password'), $query->row(1))) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

This model is linked to the login controller which uses the can_log_in function to validate credentials with verification rules (callback_validate_credentials) and return a validation set_message() if false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget `table name` in your query

```
$this->db->select('password');
$this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
$this->db->get('mytable');// add table name in your query
```